# Посоветуйте книгу по работе с сетью?

Tags: c++

Любые новые книги, где описано работа winsock2 и все что связано с сетью, на С++

Лучше конечно новую книгу 2017 и на русском языке если есть.

Comment: http://ais.khstu.ru/Electr_Books/books/Programmirovanie_v_Windows.pdf
Жалка тоже старая книга
Но думаю почитать можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Лучше конечно новую книгу 2017 и на русском языке если есть.

Не могу утверждать, но мне кажется, книг по предложенным Вами параметрам не найти. Из новых книг я встречал только одну (ENG) - [Network Programming For MS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615799) Энтони Джонса.

*Если Вы не против советов* - лучше изучайте [Boost.ASIO](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Это стоит сделать как минимум потому, что когда черновик Networking TS превратиться в законченную версию (если уже этого не случилось), многое из вышеупомянутой библиотеки окажется в стандартной библиотеке C++. Ребята, которые пилят gcc, уже запустили этот процесс :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97479/discussion-on-answer-by-isnullxbh------).

Comment: @loli Пожалуйста, в чат.